# Reference request: principalization theorem

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, and $\mathbb{I}_K$ the group of ideles.  The Hilbert class field $M$ of $K$ is the class field of the open subgroup $H = K^{\ast} \mathbb{I}_K^{S_{\infty}}$, where $$\mathbb{I}_K^{S_{\infty}} = \prod\limits_{v \mid \infty} K_v^{\ast} \prod\limits_{v \nmid \infty} \mathcal O_v^{\ast}$$ From local class field theory, we have the result that $v$ is unramified in $M$ if and only if $\mathcal O_v^{\ast}$ (or $K_v^{\ast}$ if $v$ is infinite) is contained in $H$.  Since $H$ is the smallest open subgroup of $\mathbb{I}_K$ which contains $K^{\ast}$ and all these local groups, we get that $M$ is the largest abelian extension of $K$ in which every place of $K$ is unramified.

It is a major theorem that every prime ideal of $K$ is principal in the Hilbert class field.  Does anyone know where I can find an elementary-ish proof of this result?

Answer (score 1):

It's in German, but a 3 page proof is given by Witt [here](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1954.2/ICM1954.2.ocr.pdf) (pages 71-73).

Ultimately Emil Artin showed that the result can be reduced to a purely group theoretic statement (the one contained in the paper linked above). See the discussion in Chapter V, Section 3 of Milne's [class field theory notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf).

Comment: I seem to remember that there's a beautiful proof in Zassenhaus's book on group theory,.

Comment: You have of course the chapter XIII, §4 of Artin-Tate "Class Field Theory", but can it be considered as elementary-ish ?